# Java - JDBC driver dependency in Maven Test

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, junit

At the beginning of my pom, I have a POM dependency which correctly pulls all jars etc. I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Loads of other dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.repos</groupId>
            <artifactId>external-dependencies</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- continue -->
```

As part of this dependency, I have added JDBC driver. But for tests, I cannot seem to load this driver class using `Class.forName()`.

Is it because the surefire plugin should add this dependency too? In other words, if I declare this as a global dependency would this not get considered for maven tests?

I am referring to JUnit tests, and currently getting the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

the JDBC dependency (added in com.my.repos 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT above):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```